# ESP-WROOM-02D unable to communicate using AT commands

Tags: c, esp8266, at-command

I am unable to communicate with with my device over serial. I am using the Arduino serial monitor ( tried on three different computers ) with the specified baud rate of 115200 and have played around with various others. What i'm trying to do is just send basic AT commands before integrating the chip into my embedded device. I am using usb UART to communicate with this module.

I have tried following the instructions; as mentioned default baud is 115200 and various others just in case, checked my physical wires multiple times and tried on different computers (OS's) with no luck - the only think I am able to get back is 'ready' when I click the reset button while plugged in.

Could someone please offer me some advice on how to approach this or what could be going wrong? I have tried this on 2 different wifi modules ( same make and model ) with the same results I do not understand what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Check the voltage levels of the UARTs on both sides of the link: are they both 3.3V or 5V? It's not clear from your question whether you are connecting an Arduino to a modem, a computer to modem or what you have is your Arduino hooked up to a computer and modem on the same port.

Comment: how did you wire it a how do you connect it to PC?

Comment: There are more parameters to serial communication than the baud rate: number of data bits, parity (yes, no, which), number of stop bits. Just because you're receiving "ready" it does not mean the parameters are right.

Comment: @MarcosG. on the data sheet "How to use" section it calls for 5 volts which I am giving it. I have measured the voltage as well and am receiving 5 volts. I am hooking it up to the 5 volts from another board because my USB where my UART connector is hooked up was not providing sufficient enough power. So i'm using another board to power it and the TX, RX are hooked up to my usb wire-to-uart device I use. If this doesn't address your question please let me know.

Comment: @Juraj so i'm using a USB wire to UART device that I ordered online. This allows me to connect it to serial and communicate with it from there using a serial monitor like the Arduino one.

Comment: @thebusybee I will try to look more into it, I am new to this device but looking at the datasheet all it mentions in precautions is "Precautions" working V 3.6 - 5V, default baud 115200, need to add a line break when sending "AT" I have the stop bits at 8 but not too sure about the others you're referring to, as this is essentially is out of the box; I have done nothing to do as of yet.

Comment: it is a 3.3 V device. EN needs 3.3 V too. io 15 must be pulled down, io 0 must be pulled HIGH for normal run, LOW for flashing.

Comment: see chapter 6 https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp-wroom-02u_esp-wroom-02d_datasheet_en.pdf

Comment: hmm okay, again i'm a newbie with embedded development, But I only have 4 pins ( VC, Ground, TX, RX) this particular module only exposes these four. I see the PIN out that you linked.. line 15 is not exposed to me so i'm unsure how to pull down in this case and likewise pulling high?  @Juraj

Comment: I just tried this with my bluetooth device by the same method and can change the default bluetooth name etc. i thought I would add that in there to mitigate any potential suspicions

Comment: Would you mind to [edit] your question with the new information? Here in the comments they are hidden away and you will **not** get that much feedback.

Comment: so you have the esp8266 on some adapter board?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reconnected the 5 V line it seemed to not have been optimal contact. When this was  satisfied I had to set the mode like this AT+CWMODE=3 and this seemed to do the trick.. after I was able to scan my network using AT+CWLAP and set my network using AT+CWJAP="ssid","password" still have a few challenges using this (http requests) but as of now this post can be closed and hopefully help someone else out in the future.